# Magento admin login page is blank also the product category pages

Tags: magento-1.9

when i try to enter my magento admin loign page like (domain.nl/admin), it gives me blank page. I am using magento 1.9. also when i click in my website category page or any other product page is blank. Please help me .. please

Answer (score 1):

If magento admin is showing a blank page then first you need to enable `display_errors` from `index.php`. Simply uncomment the line like below:

Replace `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

With `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Now you can see the exact error and resolve it accordingly.